# Is there something wrong with this Hive Query?

Tags: apache-spark, hiveql, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Hive and wanted to understand what's wrong with this query?

```
df_tickets = hiveContext.sql("""select  distinct oe.*,o.*,so.*
from 
efms_gold.ms_bvoip_order_extension oe 
join efms_gold.ms_order o 
on oe.ms_order_id = o.ms_order_id join efms_gold.ms_sub_order so on so.ms_order_id = o.ms_order_id 
left outer join efms_gold.ms_job j on j.entity_id = so.ms_sub_order_id 
join efms_gold.ms_task t on t.wf_job_id = j.wf_job_id 
where t.name RLIKE 'Error|Correct|Create AOTS Ticket'
and o.order_type = 900 
and o.entered_date between  date_sub(current_date(),3) and date_sub(current_date(),2) 
and j.entity_type = 5 
""")
```

I am getting the below error.

```
An error occurred while calling o68.showString.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
HashAggregate(keys=[ms_bvoip_order_extension_id#0, ms_order_id#1,
related_ontime_id#2, related_billing_id#3, related_cnr_id#4, billable_ind#5, service_biller_code#6, mrs_ind#7, 
initiate_separate_turnup_ind#8, entered_date#9, router_inst_pretest_date#10, site_surviv_ind#11, 
main_contract_type#12, on_time_ind#13, porting_ind#14, nb_fmc_ind#15, wip_status_reason#16, 
follow_up_date#17, wip_notes#18, sales_escalation_contact#19, sales_escalation_level#20, sales_escalation_office#21, 
sales_escalation_email#22, ttu_mismatch_reason#23, ... 407 more fields]
```

Comment: can we set `sc.setLogLevel("debug")` and run the query, it should give more information on where/why the error is thrown.

Comment: Tried this but seems like it's not disabling log4j logs, I'm still seeing something like this even if I set log level